# Error [D@6521f956 when trying to print an array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to print an array which is returned from a method, but I get the error [D@6521f956 in the terminal. As you can see from the code below, I am looping through my array to calculate Body Mass Index, which I then again put in a new array. It is this array which I am trying to return to my main method and print in the terminal, so far with no luck. Anything obvious I'm doing wrong?

```
public class Method {

    double [] bmiCalculation (double [] height, int [] weight){
    double [] bmiArray = new double[height.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < height.length && i < weight.length; i++) {

      double bmi = weight[i] / (height[i] * height[i]);
      bmiArray[i] = bmi;
    }

    return bmiArray;
  }
}

class Methodmain {

  public static void main (String [] args) {

    Method method = new Method();
    double [] heightArray = {1.78, 1.67, 1.59, 1.80, 1.90};
    int [] weightArray = {50, 60, 70, 80, 90};

    System.out.println(method.bmiCalculation(heightArray, weightArray));
  }
}
```

Comment: Also take a look at [What's the simplest way to print a Java array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-a-java-array)

Answer (score 1):

That's not an error - that's just what you get when you print out a `double[]` because arrays in Java don't override `toString()`.

Just use [`Arrays.toString(double[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString-double:A-) instead:

```
double[] result = method.bmiCalculation(heightArray, weightArray);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

Comment: Thank you very much for that swift answer.